# What manner of Haskell syntax is used in [$parseRoutes|/ Home GET|]?

Tags: web-applications, haskell, syntax, yesod, template-haskell

I found this code on the front page of the Yesod project:

```
import Yesod
data HelloWorld = HelloWorld
mkYesod "HelloWorld" [$parseRoutes|/ Home GET|]
instance Yesod HelloWorld where approot _ = ""
getHome = applyLayout [$hamlet|%h1 Hello World|]
main = toWaiApp HelloWorld >>= basicHandler 3000
```

What language features are used in `[$parseRoutes|/ Home GET|]` and `[$hamlet|%h1 Hello World|]` to get the $, |, / and % symbols working, and what do the symbols do?

Answer (score 17):

Those would be a [Quasiquotation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Quasiquotation).  It's a way to use Template Haskell to embed another language into Haskell.  The quasiquotes 'parseRoutes and hamlet define how to parse and interpret what is inside the bracket [$FOO| ... ].  Many more details at the link above.